# The amount of work needed to dig a hole in the ground

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy

I'm trying to calculate the amount of work that is needed to dig a hole in the ground (can be very deep) between the surface of the Earth with radius $R_{Earth}$ and some surface with radius $R$. As we know, the gravitational force inside the Earth is proportional to the radius and the second mass: $F_g(r) = \alpha \cdot m \cdot r$. If I could treat the mass m (which represents the mass of excavated soil and we can assume that the density is constant) as a rigid body then I would use the center of mass $m_c$ to calculate the required work:

$$W = \int_{R}^{R_{Earth} + \frac{R_{Earth} - R}{2}} \alpha m_crdr$$ (or via $W = \Delta E$)

But in our case, it won't work. The only idea I have is to link somehow $R$ and $m$ e.g

$$dm = \beta \cdot dr$$

(with $\beta$ as a some constant)

But it doesn't seem like a good solution

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to think about the force required to dig the layers between $R_{initial}$ and $R_{final}$? This way you could add the fact the the layers have different densities and gravity affects them based on Newton's law of gravitation.

Comment: @LinconRibeiro Yeah, exactly what I was thinking, but I don't know how to link variables. If I use $dm = const \cdot \rho (r) dr$ or even  $dm = \beta dr$ then I have something like $dr^2$ in the integral, which doesn't make sense in our case.

Comment: How deep is very deep? I assume you don't want to try digging into the mantle. ;) The thickness of the crust is <1% of the Earth's radius, so gravity due to depth in the crust doesn't vary very much. I expect that variations in density of the material you're digging through will be more important. If you do want to dig deeper, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_of_Earth#Structure has some info about density variation with depth, and a couple of relevant graphs.

Comment: @PM2Ring Very deeep ;) And whether the density is constant doesn't matter for this question. It's more about methodology.

Comment: Oh, ok. My point is that it's more realistic to ignore the change in gravitational potential with depth than to ignore the variations in the density of the extracted material.

Comment: I'm not fully sure, but I think your approach with elementary mass should work. Change in your formula work back into elementary work $dW$ and mass into elementary mass $dm$, then final work done should be $$ W = \alpha \, \beta \ \int\int r dr dr $$

Comment: As for exact form of $dm$, you can take a mass of thin cylinder, because usually holes are symmetric and circular. So in this case $$dm=\rho\, \pi l^2 dr$$ where $l$ is radius of hole

Answer (score 0):

Digging down from the surface, the work to lift the material out of the hole would be the integral from R to Rf of g(r/R)(R – r)β(dr), where R and r are measured from the center of the earth and R is the radius of the earth..

Comment: Why ? You use the modified $E_p(r) = mgr$ formula which is not true in this case.

Comment: Starting with (dm)gh, I used β(dr) as dm, (R – r) as h, and have corrected g to g(r/R).